# Program updates Linked List

Tags: c

I am trying to create a linked list with names, for example:

`Tom -> David -> John...`

In my main function, I have a `switch` menu where the program asks if you want to create a new list or exit.

When the user choose **1**, the program calls `insertIntoLinkedList(name, &head)` function where the user can add name(s) or type "end" to exit.

Everything works fine, however if the user enter `end` and choose option **1** again, the program creates a new `linked list` whereas I want to add names to an existing list.

Can someone please help me to figure out my problem? Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_SIZE 30
#define EXIT "end"

// Node structure
struct node {
  char name[NAME_SIZE];
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
typedef struct node* NodePointer;

int userChoice(void);
void insertIntoLinkedList(char [], NodePointer *);
void displayNames(NodePointer);

int nodeCounter = 0;

int main(void) {
  int choice = 99;

  do {
      printf("\n--- MENU ---\n\n");
      printf("1.\tCreate a new friend list\n");
      printf("2.\tExit o_O");
      printf("\n\n------------\n");
      printf("Go to:\t");
      choice = userChoice();

      switch (choice) {
          case 1: {
              char name[NAME_SIZE] = "";
              NodePointer head = NULL;
              while(0 != strcmp(name, EXIT)){
                  printf("Enter new friend name or \"%s\" to return back to the main menu: ", EXIT);
                  scanf("%s", name);
                  if(0 != strcmp(name, EXIT)){
                      insertIntoLinkedList(name, &head);
                      displayNames(head);
                  }
              }
              displayNames(head);
              break;
          }
          case 2: {
              printf("\n\nYou have %d node(s) in your linked list. Have a great day.\n\n", nodeCounter);
              break;
          }
          default:
              printf("There is no such option. Please choose one of the option from 1 to 2.\n");
      }
  } while(choice != 2);


  return 0;
}

int userChoice() {
  int num;
  scanf("%d", &num);
  return num;
}

void insertIntoLinkedList(char word[], NodePointer *head){
  NodePointer newNode = NULL;
  NodePointer previous = NULL;
  NodePointer current = *head;

  newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if(NULL != newNode){
      strcpy(newNode -> name, word);
      while(NULL != current && strcmp(word, current -> name) > 0){
          previous = current;
          current = current -> next;
      }

      if(NULL == previous){
          newNode -> next = current;
          *head = newNode;
      } else {
          previous -> next = newNode;
          newNode -> next = current;
      }
  }
}

void displayNames(NodePointer current) {
  nodeCounter = 0;
  if(NULL == current){
      printf("Friend list is empty... I am sorry :(\n\n");
      return;
  } else {
      printf("\nCurrent friend list: ");
      while(NULL != current){
          nodeCounter++;
          printf("%s → ", current -> name);
          current = current -> next;
      }
      printf("\nNumber of friends in your current list:\t%d\n\n", nodeCounter);
  }
}
```

Comment: OT: it is poor programming practice to `typedef` a pointer

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed include statements for header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files you actually included?

Comment: `if(NULL == previous)` then you invoked *Undefined Behavior* with `current = current -> next;`. Perhaps you intended `if (current == NULL)`?

Comment: @user3629249 can you please explain why?

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: Why to not typedef a pointer.  Because the typedef'd name can (and usually doesn't) indicate that it is a pointer

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you

Comment: In 50 lines of code -- who cares? No big deal. If 50,000 lines of code spread of multiple sources, "how many levels of indirection does this pointer really have?" -- It matters.......

Comment: this statement: `NodePointer current = *head;` is really saying: `struct node **head;`  which is not what is needed.  You need to recover the pointer to the `head` variable in the main() function.

Comment: OT:  when `malloc` fails, should inform the user via a message to `stderr` and output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "malloc failed" );`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you very much for the information about `typedef`

Comment: Please do not EDIT the code with out making it clear where the EDIT was performed.  Editing makes comments confusing and/or obsolete

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: declare `NodePointer head = NULL;` outside the scope of the outer loop.

Comment: this statement: `NodePointer head = NULL;` results in a memory leak and always starts a new list.  I.E. there will never be more than 1 entry in the linked list.  This seems to be the main problem with the code

Comment: the function: `insertIntoLinkedList()` never sets the 'next' field to NULL. instead, it sets the new node 'next' field to point to the value contained in `head`.    The result is a circular list,  where the stepping through the nodes will (most likely) never terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works fine, however if the user enter end and choose option 1 again, the program creates a new linked list whereas I want to add names to an existing list.

The issue is that you have to declare the pointer which sores the head of the list outside the `while` loop.

```
NodePointer head = NULL; 
do {
     ....

     switch (choice) {
     case 1: {
          char name[NAME_SIZE] = "";
          while(0 != strcmp(name, EXIT)){

              ....
          }
     ....
     }
} while(choice != 2);
```

Note you have declared the variable in the block scope inside the `case`. See [Scope rules in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/).
At the end of the scope the variable is not longer accessible and its content is lost. When you "reach" the code the next time, the you get a completely new initialized variable.

Answer (score 2):

Well U Can Just Declare A New Function For That. Because Every Time You Call This Function Head Is Re-declared .

```
E.g case 3:printf("\nEnter A New Friend Name:\n");
       scanf("%s",name); 
       insertIntoLinkedList(name, &head);
       displayNames(head);
       break;
```